# Can't load resource from Maven's src/main/resources folder in modular application

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system

I'm developing a Java modular application, and I need to load files from the `src/main/resources` folder, automatically generated by Maven.

My project looks like this:

```
module1
    \- src/main
        \- java
        \- resources
            \- resourcesFolder1
```

and the same for module2, that works fine.

I think that it is because the folder is "locked", so I can't read from it, so I added this line to my `module-info.java`:

```
module com.module1 {
      ...
      opens resourcesFolder1;
}
```

but the following error was throwed:

```
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package resourcesFolder1 not found in module
```

I tried putting the folder in the same directory as the `module-info.java` and in the same package that is being exported, but nothing works. What should I do?

The piece of code that loads the resources looks like this:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resourcesFolder1/resource.txt");
```

What can I do, such that I will be able to load resources from Maven's resources folder?
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1, if of any help.

Comment: Maven is adding the resources to the jar by default when executing the "package" command. What is the classpath of your running program?

Comment: What is `resourcesFolder1` and where is it in your project hierarchy?

Comment: If you have two modules m1 and m2 and m2 needs to read a resources from m1 than your design is wrong.. Better having an access provider in m1 which handles that...Apart from that the `module-info.java` file belongs to `src/main/java` nowhere else...The module-info declares the module but you can not open a module for a single file..like a resources file..(access beyond boundaries) which is more or less equivalent to an maven artifacts (one pom.xml file)..or jar file ...

Comment: @JacobG. it is the folder from which I load the resources, and it is inside the `src/main/resources` folder.

Comment: @khmarbaise my second module don't read resources from the first, I just informed that it existed to give a background on what situation the problem is happening.